# Print the names of all files in the current directory - c

Tags: c

I need to print the names of all files in the current directory. 
but I must do it only with system calls, so I have the `SYS_OPEN, SYS_GETDENTS, SYS_READ` etc. I'm working on Ubuntu.
How can I do it?
I tried to use this:

```
system_call(SYS_OPEN, ".", 0, 0777);
```

and then to `READ` from and write to `STDOUT`.. but it's not working.

** I cannot use the standard library.
Thank you!

EDIT:
an example code:
** there is a file in assembly, with the function "system call" that do the call.
    #include "util.h"

```
#define SYS_WRITE 4

#define SYS_OPEN 5

#define SYS_CLOSE 6

#define SYS_READ 3

#define SYS_LSEEK 19

#define SYS_GETDENTS 141

#define BUF_SIZE 1024

#define STDOUT 1

 struct linux_dirent {
           long           d_ino;
           int         d_off;

           unsigned short d_reclen;

           char           d_name[];

       };         

int main (int argc , char* argv[], char* envp[])

{

   int fd=0;

   int nread;

   char * nread_str;

   char buf[BUF_SIZE];

   struct linux_dirent *d;

           int bpos;

           char d_type;

  fd=system_call(SYS_OPEN,".", 0 , 0);
          for ( ; ; ) {

               nread = system_call(SYS_GETDENTS, fd, buf, BUF_SIZE);

               if (nread == -1)              

        system_call(SYS_WRITE,STDOUT, "error-getdents",BUF_SIZE);

               if (nread == 0)

                   break;

          system_call(SYS_WRITE,STDOUT, "--------------- nread=%d ---------------\n",100);

      nread_str=itoa(nread);      

          system_call(SYS_WRITE,STDOUT, nread_str,100);                      

          system_call(SYS_WRITE,STDOUT, "i-node#  file type  d_reclen  d_off   d_name\n",100);

               for (bpos = 0; bpos < nread;) {

                   d = (struct linux_dirent *) (buf + bpos);

                  /* printf("%8ld  ", d->d_ino);**/

                   d_type = *(buf + bpos + d->d_reclen - 1);


                  /* printf("%4d %10lld  %s\n", d->d_reclen,
                           (long long) d->d_off, (char *) d->d_name);**/
                   bpos += d->d_reclen;
               }
           }

}
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: what about calling `ls` command?

Comment: I have to print the names into stdout (ls will help here. you are right) but also into a file.. the instructions are to use SYS_GETDENTS, SYS_OPEN etc.. to write a c program

Comment: The name of the question is wrong. The task is apparently not to print out lists of filenames. Instead it is a homwork to practice syscalls.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <dirent.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
  {
DIR *dir;
struct dirent *ent;
if ((dir = opendir ("c:\\")) != NULL) {
  /* print all the files and directories within directory */
  while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {
    printf ("%s\n", ent->d_name);
  }
  closedir (dir);
} else {
  /* could not open directory */
  perror ("");
  return EXIT_FAILURE;}
}
```

Comment: You get a +1 despite the need to brush up on indentation

Comment: Thank you, but they let us to include only "utils.h", thats mean that we have only strlen, atoia and strcmp. All the other are system calls: SYS_OPEN, SYS_READ, SYS_CLOSE, SYS_GETDENTS, SYS_WRITE etc.

Comment: You can certainly rewrite the code using the syscalls. You could also look into the library code for the functions used here, as it certainly runs the syscalls in the background.

Answer (score -1):

Read the manual pages for `opendir` etc.

See http://linux.die.net/man/3/opendir

Comment: Thank you, but they let us to include only "utils.h", thats mean that we have only strlen, atoia and strcmp. All the other are system calls: SYS_OPEN, SYS_READ, SYS_CLOSE, SYS_GETDENTS, SYS_WRITE etc.

Comment: Who are "they" - We fault the Nazis in the last war

Comment: "lecutrers" - Who are they. Besides the Americans always turn up late

Comment: The very same "they" that demand people to print strings without using quotes, calculate sines only using the operand "&", and so one? Men in Black?

Comment: it's possible to use strings, but not all the operations. I have edited my topic and added a code, my code should be like this, but this code doesn't working. Maybe it would help you to get a solution. Thank you!